# Native bracket pair colorization extension doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to use Native bracket pair colorization by putting "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true in settings.jason file, but it doesn't work.

what did I do wrong?
here's my settings.json file code.

```
{
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
  },
  "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
    "default": "right",
    "jupyter-notebook": "left"
  },

  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Darker",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "autoprefixer.formatOnSave": true,
  "autoprefixer.options": {
    "browsers": [
      "last 4 versions" /* 가장 최신 버전에서 4단계 아래 버전까지 지원합니다. */,
      "ie >= 9" /* IE9 버전 이상만 지원합니다. */,
      "> 5%" /* 전 세계 브라우저 사용률 중 5% 를 초과하는 브라우저만 대응합니다. */
    ]
  },
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true
}
```

help!

Answer (score 0):

try this steps on visual studio code

[image]

Comment: what is this different from having `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true` in your settings file

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the feature, you might need to configure what exactly the color should the editor use for highlighting.

```
    {
  // ...
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#ffb86c",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#8be9fd",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#bd93f9",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#50fa7b",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#f1fa8c",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#abb2c0",
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff5555"
  }
}
```

this is the guide I used and configured successfully.
[Link][1]
[1]: https://dev.to/amanhimself/how-to-configure-vscode-bracket-pair-colors-natively-3nl

You might also need to disable some extensions as there's possible conflicts, namely between indentation and brackets

Answer (score -1):

Check if .vscode>setting.json exists in the project root directory.

Comment: I can guess where you're going with this, but don't make your readers guess. spell it out.